# How to make cell value change from one cell to another when I input new value to one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I would like to ask how to make and write formula that make cell value change from one cell to another when i input new value to that cell.
etc           A1 cell have 111
               B1 cell have 222
               C1 cell have 333
               D1 cell have 444
In this situation, When I put new value 555 to A1 ...... I want to get is
 A1 have 555
B1 have 111
C1 have 222
D1 have 333
like that. Please let me know formula.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a push-down stack or history of values entered in cell **A1**.

Enter the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, C As Range, D As Range
    Dim temp As Variant

    Set A = Range("A1")
    Set B = Range("B1")
    Set C = Range("C1")
    Set D = Range("D1")

    If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        temp = [A]
        Application.Undo
        [D] = [C]
        [C] = [B]
        [B] = [A]
        [A] = temp
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**